# Best django fieldtype(postgres datatype) to save python hashlib hexdigest (40 characters)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

What is the best field type in django to save a fixed length (40 characters) hexdigest? This field is indexed and needs to be optimized for storage and querying. Currently we use `CharField` but doesn't seem to be optimal as this is varchar

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=["my_field"])]
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having when using the CharField?

Comment: Thanks. There are no issues. As mentioned, I was wondering if there was a better field which we could use. We had a table with 100 million+ rows and the index alone on this field was 21 GB.  A UUID field takes much less space, but that is 32 characters (without the hyphens)

Comment: You mention a UUID field but your question was about a 40 char hex digest, if the format of the field does not matter the source/purpose of the data and the field would be enlightening